# When comparing the ACT and SAT by converting both measurements into z scores, why is it that the person with the smaller z score has the better test?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, standardization

I was reading this article: https://medium.com/omarelgabrys-blog/statistics-probability-probability-distribution-35818d301cf4#fbef

and, in one section of the article, the author compares two students. One student took the SAT and the other student took the ACT. He wants to know which student did better and so he standardized their scores.

One student has z=1 and the other student ha z=0.6. In other words, the latter students has a value that is closer to the average. Why does this mean that this student did better on his test than the other student did on his?

I would expect that we would conclude that the person with a score further from the average would have done better on the test.

Edit: both scores were above their respective averages.

Comment: Well if they got it right, maybe they’d call themselves “Large”. One correction to your logic: further is only better if the score is ABOVE average.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. I'll edit my question. Both scores were above their respective averages. .

Comment: To clarify the joke in my first comment, that link gets it wrong. $z=1$ is the higher score.